# Does it sound good to write "With best compliments from" in an invitation?

Tags: phrases, american-english, politeness

Again it's somewhat similar to my previous question, but I need to know it too. I am preparing contents for a wedding card, I have little doubt in writing **With best compliments from** as the last line of the invitation, as according to my knowledge, this phrase is written when you gift or compliment someone. Is it okay to write it as following?

```
With best compliments from

Mr. Xyz, Nearest & Dearest
```

Comment: Did you try to find other wedding cards on the internet? What do you exactly want to mean with "with best compliments from"?

Comment: Not on the internet but recently I found a wedding card with this phrase at home.

Comment: What is the purpose of the card? You need to be more specific about your question.

Comment: Any kind of invitation it can be, be it for a party, reception or wedding.

Comment: Then, please edit your question. Your question states "I am preparing contents for a wedding card". What is the purpose of your wedding card? What are the contents?

Comment: I just need to know if that phrase can be written at the end or not or whether it sounds good or not for any invitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never encountered that phrase, and it sounds to me like it was written by somebody for whom English is a second language. (Not that there's anything wrong with having English as a second language, of course!) The closest standard closing that I'm familiar with is "With best wishes." But actually, it sounds like you are structuring this as a letter, but if you are doing wedding invitations that's not standard. TheKnot.com has a good set of info on standard invitation text options [here](https://www.theknot.com/content/standard-wedding-invitation-wording-examples).